# Ripple effect and icons not showing on Framework7

Tags: javascript, android, css, cordova, html-framework-7

I have a simple Framework7 app and I'm trying the Google material design, everything works except icons and the ripple effect (the visual effect when the user clicks on a clickable element). Icons don't show at all and the ripple effect looks like the iOS one. I'm including the framework7 css an the framework.min.js file as they are (version 1.5.3). Do I need to recompile the JS file? [image]

Here my app.js:

```
// Initialize app
var myApp = new Framework7();

// If we need to use custom DOM library, let's save it to $$ variable:
var $$ = Dom7;

// Add view
var mainView = myApp.addView('.view-main', {
  // Because we want to use dynamic navbar, we need to enable it for this view:
  dynamicNavbar: true
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the ripple effect, you have to active it first. To active material theme (ripple effect) you have init your app with this :

```
// Initialize app
var myApp = new Framework7({
  // Enable Material theme
  material: true,
});
```

If you set material to `true`, the ripple effect will be activated. And to disable ripple effect in material theme, you have to add `materialRipple: false` to your app initialize.

```
// Initialize app
var myApp = new Framework7({
  // Enable Material theme
  material: true,
  materialRipple: false,
});
```